# Attempting to use docker-client from Spotify and am getting various errors

Tags: java, docker

I want to be able to interact with Docker from a Java program which is currently running within Eclipse on Windows. I followed the instructions found here: https://github.com/spotify/docker-client

I created a Maven project and tried to run the sample code specified in the Readme. I first got "connection refused" errors but then tried to create the DockerClient object by specifying a uri:

uri(URI.create("unix:///var/run/docker.sock"))

And this resulted in UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unknown errors. It appears that a library called "c.dll" is being looked for and indeed when I create a fake library called this and place it in one of folders in the Library Path, I get a different error: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Operation completed successfully.

I am assuming the latter error comes from the c.dll not having the correct entry points.

So my questions at this point are: Am I right in assuming that creating the DockerClient using the URI is the correct way to go? If so, is it indeed looking for c.dll and if so, where can I find a "good" c.dll so the code will work?

Or has anyone else managed to get DockerClient code to work on Windows, perhaps without having to find the right c.dll?

Comment: No code, what is the relation with Java?

Comment: Running Java Docker client and seem to be getting Java errors such as UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: Ah, annoying that specifically docker runs into this. Docker on windows is still a bit new. My advice is to launch a linux VM and try it in there

Comment: That is an approach but running on Windows is useful. However, if it works on Linux but not Windows, I guess we learned something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the cause was this client did not support **npipe**.

But some time ago it was implemented for this client in the GitHub Pull request: [Support windows named pipe](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/issues/875).

At now, this client initialization works in Windows too:

```java
DockerClient docker = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build();
```